# Product of $A$ with the adjoint of $A$: why are all nondiagonal elements zero?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Let \begin{align*} A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 4 \\ 3 & 2 & 1 \\ 6 & 8 & 2 \end{pmatrix}. \end{align*} We have $\det(A) = 44$. The cofactor matrix corresponding with $A$ is \begin{align*} C = \begin{pmatrix} -4 & 0 & 12 \\ 28 & -22 & 4 \\ -6 & 11 & -4 \end{pmatrix}. \end{align*} Hence the adjugate matrix of $A$ is \begin{align*} C^T = \begin{pmatrix} -4 & 28 & -6 \\ 0 & -22 & 11 \\ 12 & 4 & -4 \end{pmatrix}. \end{align*} Then \begin{align*} A C^T = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 4 \\ 3 & 2 & 1 \\ 6 & 8 & 2 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} -4 & 28 & -6 \\ 0 & -22 & 11 \\ 12 & 4 & -4 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 44 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 44 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 44 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} \det(A) & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & \det(A) & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \det(A) \end{pmatrix}. \end{align*}

Now I'm trying to understand in an intuitive manner why all the elements $a_{ij}$ for $i \neq j$ are zero. I understand why the diagonal elements are all $44$. For $a_{11}$ this is just Laplace expansion along the first row, i.e. \begin{align*} \sum_{j=1}^3 (-1)^{1+j} a_{1j} \det(M_{1j}) = \sum_{k=1}^3 a_{1k} C_{1k}, \end{align*} with $C_{1k} = (-1)^{1+j} \det(M_{1j})$.

Now, let's say we compute $a_{12}$. Then we multiply row $1$ of $A$ with column $2$ of $C^T$, or equivalently with row $2$ of the cofactor matrix $C$, since it is the transpose. I don't see why this should always equal zero? Why is $ \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 4 \end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix} 28 & -22 & 4 \end{pmatrix} = 0 $?

Comment: We know that $A^{-1}=\frac{C^{T}} {det (A)}$. Can you clarify what exactly you are looking for ?

Comment: You're not computing $a_{ij}$ here, since those are customarily the $ij$ entries of $A$. You're computing the $ij$ entries of the matrix $AC^\top$, so you should use a different letter, for sure.

Answer (score 2):

Because this is the Laplace expansion for the determinant of a matrix with two identical rows.

Comment: What matrix would that be then, and how do I find it?

Comment: In your example, replace the second row of $A$ with the first row, leaving everything else the same.

Comment: So that would give me $A' = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 4 \\ 6 & 8 & 2 \end{pmatrix}$. Now you say the zero results because I compute the Laplace expansion of this along the first row? If I do that I get: $(-1)^2 (1) \det \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 4 \\ 8 & 2 \end{pmatrix} + (-1)^3 (2) \det \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 4 \\ 6 & 2 \end{pmatrix} + (-4)^4 (4) \det \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 6 & 8 \end{pmatrix}$. If I only use the cofactors, I get $1(-28) - 1 (-22) + 1(-4)$. This are not the same components as the cofactors above? They differ by a sign.

Comment: No, you're still expanding along the second row. Think about what you did in your post.

Comment: I don't see it... Maybe if you would help me some more. I don't know what I did wrong.

Comment: I found the correct cofactors when I expanded along the second row. That gave me $ - \det \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 4 \\ 8 & 2 \end{pmatrix} + \det \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 4 \\ 6 & 2 \end{pmatrix} - \det \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 6 & 8 \end{pmatrix}.$ This gives me $-(-28) + (-22) -(-4)$ , which are the correct cofactors. So I should expand along the second row? When you said first one.

Comment: No, I said *replace* the (entries of the) second row with the (entries of the) first row. But you still do the Laplace expansion along the second row.